# We neeed apache .htaccess redirect per languages url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We are abandoning the management of some languages ​​on our site. We would like to perform a 301 redirect

I need this langeage redirect 301 rule in apache .htaccess:

`/es /pt /ru`
etc..

to
`/en`

and
`/es/page_path /pt/page_path /ru/page_path`
etc...

to
`/en/page_path`

Could you please help me?

tks Simone

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878)

Comment: What have you tried, how did it not work? This site is not a "make this for me" service, you are supposed to make a proper effort yourself first. _Plenty_ of explanations on the basics of URL rewriting are available, for example [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the methods below.  If you have other rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` you probably want to use the rewrite rule, otherwise I'd stick wit hthe simpler alias redirects.

When testing, start with temporary (302) redirects and then change them to permanent (301) redirects once you know they are working.  This prevents your own browser from caching bad redirects which prevents you from testing to see if fixes work.

#### Using mod_alias

```
Redirect permanent /es /en
Redirect permanent /pt /en
Redirect permanent /ru /en
```

#### Using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule "^/?(es|pt|ru)(/.*)?$" "/en$2" [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much, it's almost perfect but there is a problem, if I have a url that starts with one of the language prefix codes. for example
/essential
becomes
/ensential

probably you have to work with es/ pt/ etc...
and then manage the homepages individually

Comment: If the URL path is localized you won't be able to use that HD access to do the redirects. You will need to keep translations for those languages and use a programming language to look up the translations and redirect appropriately.

Comment: I changhed like that:    RewriteRule "^/?(es/|pt/|ru/)(.*)$" "/en/$2" [L,R=301]    . It seems to work. Whant do you think?

Comment: I think I found a rule that would redirect `/es`  `/es/` and `/es/foo` but not `/essential`.  It's edited into the answer.

Comment: Now it seems perfetc. many thanks